# Sending a datefield through a url, filter items

Tags: django

I am making a basic invoice system where I've created billing periods and items. I select and item and when it was "bought" and then I want to filter the items by the months they were applied. I am new to Django, and I can't seem to figure out how I would set up the URL. This is what I have thus far from crawling through the documentation.

```
## urls.py
url(r'^invoice/invoice-list/(P<year>[0-9]{4})-(?P<month>[-\w]+)-(p<year>[0-9]{4})-(p<month>[-\w]+)', 'invoices.views.InvoiceDetail', name='invoice-detail')



## invoice-list.html
{% for period in bill_period %}
   <li> <a href="{% url 'invoice-detail' period.start_date|date:"F Y" period.end_date|date:"F Y" %}">{{ period.start_date | date }} - {{ period.end_date | date}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}



## views.py
@login_required
def invoicelist(request):
    p = Bill_Period.objects.filter()
    return render_to_response('invoice-list.html', {'bill_period': p})

def InvoiceDetail(request, id=id):
    invoice_details = invoice.objects.filter(date_of_service__range=(period.start_date, period.end_date))
    current_user = request.user
    context = {'invoice_details': invoice_details}
    return render(request, 'invoice-detail.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, your URL regular expression is wrong; the named groups `year` and `month` are duplicated twice. I'm guessing you'd want to change two of those into `date` and `id`

when you use named groups in your URL regular expressions, those named groups would be passed to the views as additional arguments. Thus, your InvoiceDetail function (note: pep8 recommends lowercased & underscores for function names) would be called as `InvoiceDetail(request, year, month, date, id)`, once you correct your URL.

From then, you can use the values of year, month, date to filter your invoices.

There's several improvements you can make, though. First of all, `year, month, and date` should be grouped together in one regex group, say `timestamp`. Now, your `InvoiceDetail` function would receive `timestamp` as a string, but then you can use `datetime.strptime()` (or even easier, `dateutil.parse()`) to convert that string to a `datetime` object for database queries.

Second of all, you may want to consider putting the filter values in the GET query instead of hardcoding them in the URL (ie. something like `?datetime=2015-05-19&id=abcdef`). Not only would you not have to write a complicated regex, you'd also get a much more flexible URL.